# Laravel old() function not working --- flash dose not work (stoped working!!)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to use `old()` in Laravel but it doesn't work.

In my controller:

```php
dd(back()->withInput());
```

this is the session result

```php
#session: Store {#364 ▼
#id: "dyNmtFJVQCQmcCob4SPYEBzWHJ6TJeM9X0mzWWu7"
#name: "laravel_session"
#attributes: array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "NVJATvxuHRlGbAC1jUEIjS6gbLQQEWPIIV41fLYd"
  "url" => []
  "_previous" => array:1 [▼
    "url" => "http://localhost:8000/units/23/rents/create"
  ]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "_old_input"
    ]
  ]
  "login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 1
  "_old_input" => array:5 [▼
    "_token" => "NVJATvxuHRlGbAC1jUEIjS6gbLQQEWPIIV41fLYd"
    "contract_id" => "20"
    "unit_id" => "23"
    "amount_paid" => "1"
    "submit" => "submit"
  ]
]
#handler: FileSessionHandler {#363 ▶}
#started: true
```

`value="{{ old('amount_paid')}}"` I would get empty field

`value="{{ old('amount_paid','test') }}"` I would get 'test' in the field

I'm using Laravel 5.6

**EDIT**
to clarify the above code it to debug
this is my original code
controller

```php
return back()->withInput();
```

view

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label> amount paid  </label>
    <input type="float" class="form-control" name="amount_paid" value="{{ old('amount_paid')}}" required>
</div>
```

**adding the method that handle the request**

```
        public function store(Request $request)
{
    // updating the amount paid
    $rent = new Rent;
    $rent->amount_paid = $request->amount_paid;


    try {
        $rent->save();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        //return to the form and populate it
        return back()->withInput();
    }
    return redirect('units/'.$request->unit_id);
```

** update **
It appear that session->flash is not working.

I tried a new installation of laravel and it is working fine

Comment: Where are you using it ? Your view ?

Comment: I thought you're supposed to `return back->with...()` as opposed to just `back()->with...()` or `dd(back()->with...())` ??

Comment: yes I am using it in my view

Comment: Can you add the whole method that handles the request?

Comment: I have added it. Apparently flash is not working ( only with my main app ) . I have used new instillation and it is working !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to session it self.

I have 2

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

one in middleware and another in $middlewareGroups[web].

this was a result of following a tutorial in youtube months ago to implement localisation :(